# Ruby on Rails - Foreign key to reference index other than primary key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship

In Ruby on Rails, how can I create relationship in which foreign key references field other than primary key? How to do that in migration or in model class? I am using MySQL.

Thanks,

Edit: Lets say I have two table A and B. In B, i have a field called name and in A I have b_name. How do I specify that

Comment: You want a custom `foreign key`?

Comment: I have updated my question with an example

Comment: if i am not wrong all the examples tell me how to specify b_name as foreign key. How do I ask ruby to reference `name` instead of primary key. Is it by specifying :reference => 'b_name' ?

Comment: Just simple as like that. In A you can specify `foreign_key: 'b_name'` thats it.

Comment: How does ruby know that `b_name` is attached to `name` and not primary key of Model B :s

Comment: The default primary key will be the `id` unless you change it.So the Rails knows it.

Comment: That is the problem... I don't want to link it to primary key. Primary key is `id` but I want to link it to `name` instead of `id`

Comment: I didn't get it.You want `name` as primary key instead of `id`?

Comment: No. primary key of table `B` is `id`, but I want to associate `name` field of table `B` with `b_name` of table `A`.

Comment: Yeah!That's what i told before.You can achieve it through by setting `foreign_key: 'b_name'` in A model.

Comment: Isn't ruby associate `b_name` to `id` field of table `B`?

Comment: No.It associates `b_name` to `name` field of Table B.

Comment: okkkk... and if `b_name` is named something like `printable_name`, even then ruby can guess the association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it through a `foreign_key` option within the `Model` level

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :B, foreign_key: 'some_other_column'

end
```

If you haven't specified the `foreign_key` option,`Rails` by default looks for `B_id`.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the column name that is the foreign key in your table like this:

```
Class ModelA  < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :models, foreign_key: 'another_id'
```

Above association says, models table has a column called 'another_id'.

Read more about various options [in the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference).

Answer (score 3):

The [`foreign_key`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key) arg is what you need, as mentioned by `pavan` and `emaillenin`, however, I would like to stress that in order to get it to work, I've found you have to apply it to both parts of the association:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts, foreign_key: "post"
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "post"
end
```

To reference in the migration / db, you'd literally just replace the `____id` column with another one. Still would be an integer etc, except it would have a different name

Comment: You're growing well! I see you a lot on here - good to see you've braved the downvotes a lot of people love to give!